# How do I start jstatd in my local machine?

Tags: java, visualvm, jvisualvm, jstatd

I was trying all the steps mentioned in [this link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/share/jstatd.html) , but unfortunately getting the same old error like

```
Could not create remote object
access denied ("java.util.PropertyPermission" 
"java.rmi.server.ignoreSubClasses" "write")
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied 
("java.util.PropertyPermission" "java.rmi.server.ignoreSubClasses" 
"write")
at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:472)
at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:884)
at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:549)
at java.lang.System.setProperty(System.java:792)
at sun.tools.jstatd.Jstatd.main(Jstatd.java:139)
```

Hope someone can point out the error that I'm doing . By the way, this is how my `jstatd.all.policy` file looks like

```
bismoy@ap-l0059:~/Downloads/java/bin$ cat jstatd.all.policy 
grant codebase "file:/home/bismoy/Downloads/java/lib/tools.jar" {
permission java.security.AllPermission;
};
```

[image]

Comment: What command parameters are you using?

Comment: @VivekRatanSinha jstatd -J-Djava.security.policy=/home/user/jstatd.all.policy

Comment: Location of `jstatd.all.policy` file is `/home/user` as per your command line, but is `~/Downloads/java/bin` as per your question. Is this the cause of your problem?

Comment: @VivekRatanSinha have updated the question, strangely now I don't see any response .

Comment: It means that you have successfully started jstatd :) You can confirm that using ps command.

Comment: @VivekRatanSinha   bismoy@ap-l0059:~/Downloads/java/bin$ ps -ef | grep jstatd
bismoy    2424  1747  0 15:49 pts/0    00:00:05 jstatd -J-Djava.security.policy=/home/bismoy/.jstatd.all.policy
bismoy    4432  1747  0 16:16 ?        00:00:00 gedit /home/bismoy/Downloads/java/bin/jstatd.all.policy
bismoy    4449  2405  0 16:17 pts/0    00:00:01 jstatd -J-Djava.security.policy=/home/bismoy/Downloads/java/bin/jstatd.all.policy
bismoy    4589  4575  0 16:21 pts/11   00:00:00 grep --color=auto jstatd

Comment: I guess it's up now !

Comment: Glad to help. Please mark my answer appropriately. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Location of `jstatd.all.policy` file is `/home/user` as per your command line, but is `~/Downloads/java/bin` as per your question. Make sure to use correct paths.